# How do I use conditions properly in PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

I wanted to do a condition wherein I put values (000000) in DATE_COMPLETED if it see's the FLAG_CLOSED = Y and if its not Y then do nothing

```
SELECT 
 "JOB",
 "SUFFIX", 
 "SUFFIX", 
 "DATE_COMPLETED", 
 "FLAG_CLOSED",

CASE "DATE_COMPLETED" 
WHEN "FLAG_CLOSED"='Y' 
THEN "DATE_COMPLETED"='000000' 
END "DATE_COMPLETED"

FROM "JOB_OPERATIONS"
```

What I got

```
SQL Execution Error
[LNA][PSQL][SQL Engine]Syntax Error: SELECT 
 "JOB",
 "SUFFIX", 
 "SUFFIX", 
 "DATE_COMPLETED", 
 "FLAG_CLOSED",

CASE "DATE_COMPLETED" WHEN "FLAG_CLOSED" << ??? >> = 'Y' THEN "DATE_COMPLETED" = '000000' END "DATE_COMPLETED"
FROM JOB_OPERATIONS
```

Comment: Unrelated, but: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to change the `DATE_COMPLETED` column in your table. You can't do that with a SELECT statement. CASE / WHEN / THEN helps construct output. UPDATE statements allow clauses like `DATE_COMPLETED='000000'` that change columns.

Try something like this.

```sql
SELECT  "JOB",  "SUFFIX", "SUFFIX", "DATE_COMPLETED", "FLAG_CLOSED",
        CASE WHEN "FLAG_CLOSED"='Y' THEN '000000' 
             ELSE "DATE_COMPLETED" END "CLOSED_DATE_COMPLETED" 
FROM "JOB_OPERATIONS"
```

I named your CASE-computed output column `CLOSED_DATE_COMPLETED` so it won't collide with the `DATE_COMPLETED` colum you already mentioned.

Comment: Note that this will result in an error if `DATE_COMPLETED` is a `DATE`  column (which the name suggests) as `'000000'` is not a valid DATE value.

Answer (score 0):

Syntax is either:

```
CASE a WHEN b
```

... or:

```
CASE when a=b
```

To return the value of `DATE_COMPLETED` depending on the flag, you can do this:

```
CASE "FLAG_CLOSED"
    WHEN 'Y' THEN '000000'
    ELSE "DATE_COMPLETED"
END AS "DATE_COMPLETED"
```

Beware that you need to produce a coherent column type. If `DATE_COMPLETED` is not text, you'll need to cast it.